# Decrypting wpa_supplicant.conf on Samsung Galaxy mobiles

Tags: wi-fi, encryption, password, samsung-galaxy-s-5, wpa-supplicant

When I do `cat` on `wpa_supplicant.conf` file on Samsung mobiles, I see that the passwords are encrypted. But when I open the same file on LG mobiles, I can see the passwords in plain text.

This is what I see on my Galaxy S5. The information below is for my network which has a WPA password `77807780` (`psk` is the encrypted passkey):

```
network={
        ssid=""
        psk=fce6c4f64304b00c5783199bbd2b1f91
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        priority=10
        frequency=2462
        autojoin=1
        usable_internet=0
        skip_internet_check=0
}
```

Is this a feature on Samsung mobiles? What kind of encryption is used to encrypt the password and how to decrypt them?

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm that it's in plain text on LG Nexus 4. Researching a bit also confirms that Samsung does encrypt/hash it, but I haven't found the method yet.

Comment: On my Galaxy S5, it uses OpenSSL's EVP_Encrypt* methods with the EVP_aes_128_cbc cipher, i.e. AES with a 128-bit key in CBC mode. It makes sense since all encrypted PSKs I've seen have a length modulo 32 hex chars (32*4 bits = 128 bits, the block size of AES). No idea what's being used as the key or the IV.

Comment: Related: [Retrieve WiFi password](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132391/44325), [How to recover stored wifi password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217603/44325)

Answer (score 3):

Use wpa_supplicant's [wpa_passphrase](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_passphrase) tool to create your own "real" psk. Actually, the plain-text psk (double-quoted) must be processed at every startup and config reload to generate the real, 64 hex-digit (256-bit) psk. So, using wpa_passphrase to manually create the fully-processed PSK actually [optimizes](https://github.com/ystk/debian-wpasupplicant/blob/master/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf#L300-L303) wpa_supplicant's startup & config reload time. :)

About decrypting them... wpa_supplicant uses an AES-based cipher, which is well respected. I think TKIP is deprecated and possibly exploitable.

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution:

- Go to root browser
- Go to `/etc/secure_storage/.system.wpa_supplicant` then delete this folder (only ".secure.supplicant.conf"), then reboot.
- Strange number gone

Note: It only works for Samsung devices, all saved WiFi hotspots will be lost for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Find the following line in `build.prop`:

```
ro.securestorage.support=true
```

and change it to

```
ro.securestorage.support=false
```

Then reboot the device. Now retype password of your Wi-Fi network.

If your phone is rooted, you can view passwords either by reading `wpa_supplicant.conf` file or by installing "WiFi Key Recovery" app.

Comment: currently i don't have a device to test your solution on, but anyway that's not what i asked for i need to know the encryption type and how to decrypt an already encrypted password

Comment: This is the same as the one above that deletes the secure storage folder, but applies to everything that uses Secure Server.

Comment: @MOHAMMAD it's unlikely you will ever decrypt one once encrypted.