# How to decrypt a recovered password on Samsung S6?

Tags: encryption, samsung-galaxy-s-6, wifi-password

I have rooted my Samsung S6 so that I could recover wifi passwords. But the app **Wifi password Recovery** find an encrypted password.

Is it possible to find the original password?

If so, how can I do to see it?

[image: A screenshoot of wifi password recovery app]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related: [Decrypting wpa_supplicant.conf on Samsung Galaxy mobiles](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/95923/44325), but doesn't have the answer to decrypt the existing pass.

Comment: Also, [Retrieve WiFi password](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132391/44325) which was linked from [How to recover stored wifi password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217665/44325)

Comment: I think the answer is NO

Comment: The PSK is generated from the WPA passphrase using hashing. Hash algorithms are one-way (you can not reverse it easily). So the only possible way is a brute-force attack by trying every possible password, generate the PDK and look if it matches. Depending on the length of the WPA passphrase the used characters and the hardware you have this can take weeks or even years. As far as I remember most Wifi devices also allow to directly use the PSK instead of the password. Not sure if this is still the case today andhow it is on Android.

Comment: So I there is no hope?